# SharePoint JavaScript read value of rich text multiline field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, richtextbox

I have a SharePoint solution and I will like to validate the Rich Text Multiline field.  I have the following code incorporated.

The problem is that when save is initially selected the function picks up the value in the text box.  If there is a validation error I will display an error message explaining to the user what must be changed.  When the value in the text box is changed and save is selected a second time the original value is being picked up and not the update value in the text box.

How can I pick up the updated value in the multiline rich text box each time save is selected?

```
function findFieldControl(fieldTitle)
{

var control = $('[title="' + fieldTitle + '"]');
return control;
}

function PreSaveAction(){

  var commentsBox = findFieldControl('Comments')

  alert(commentsBox.val());

}
```

Comment: Can you add more content to how you are running everything? Do you have `PreSaveAction()` running on clicking `save`?

Comment: Yes when I press save in the sharepoint window it activates that PreSaveAction function listed above.  All the script needs to do I run an alert of the comments box contents.  However when I change the comments box contents and press save again to active the PreSaveAction the alert does not display the new edited comments but the first set of comments that were changed.

Comment: Can you post your code to show how your textbox is? Did you create it with divs or is this within a custom New Form? Trying to replicate..

Comment: It is a custom New Form in share point

Comment: <tr>
      <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
       <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Comments</nobr>
       </H3>
      </td>
      <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
       <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff9{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Comments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff9',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Comments')}"/>
       <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff9description{$Pos}" FieldName="Comments" ControlMode="New"/>
      </td>
     </tr>

Comment: above is the html row used on the custom new form that links to a list the a field named Comments that where the type of field is rich text

Comment: when i inspect the element this is the id for the field ctl00_ctl30_g_1d1d31bd_63aa_4270_a04e_7b15d371eb09_ff91_ctl00_ctl00_TextField

Comment: Are you not wanting to just use the Id value of the comment box and use the textContent?